# sha1 function in Javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

How to convert the following js to python?

```
function sha1(str1,raw)
{
    var hexcase = 0;
    var chrsz   = 8;
    str1 = utf16to8(str1);

    function utf16to8(str) 
    {
        var out, i, len, c;

        out = "";
        len = str.length;
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
            c = str.charCodeAt(i);
            if ((c >= 0x0001) && (c <= 0x007F)) 
            {
                out += str.charAt(i);
            } 
            else if (c > 0x07FF) 
            {
                out += String.fromCharCode(0xE0 | ((c >> 12) & 0x0F));
                out += String.fromCharCode(0x80 | ((c >>  6) & 0x3F));
                out += String.fromCharCode(0x80 | ((c >>  0) & 0x3F));
            } 
            else 
            {
                out += String.fromCharCode(0xC0 | ((c >>  6) & 0x1F));
                out += String.fromCharCode(0x80 | ((c >>  0) & 0x3F));
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    function hex_sha1(s)
    {
        return binb2hex(core_sha1(str2binb(s),s.length * chrsz));
    }

    function str_sha1(s)
    {
        return binb2str(core_sha1(str2binb(s),s.length * chrsz));
    }

    function binb2hex(binarray) 
    {
        var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
        var str = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) 
        {
            str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
                    hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i%4)*8 )) & 0xF);
        }
        return str;
    }

    function binb2str(bin) 
    {
        var str = "";
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for(var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
            str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i>>5] >>> (32 - chrsz - i%32)) & mask);
        return str;
    }

    function str2binb(str2) 
    {
        var bin = Array();
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for(var i = 0; i < str2.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
            bin[i>>5] |= (str2.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (32 - chrsz - i%32);
        return bin;
    }

    function safe_add(x, y) 
    {
        var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
        var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
        return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
    }

    function rol(num, cnt) 
    {
        return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
    }

    function sha1_ft(t, b, c, d) 
    {
        if(t < 20) 
            return (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
        if(t < 40) 
            return b ^ c ^ d;
        if(t < 60) 
            return (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
        return b ^ c ^ d;
    }

    function sha1_kt(t) 
    {
        return (t < 20) ? 1518500249 : (t < 40) ? 1859775393 : (t < 60) ? -1894007588 : -899497514;
    }

    function core_sha1(x, len) 
    {
        x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - len % 32);
        x[((len + 64 >> 9) << 4) + 15] = len;

        var w = Array(80);
        var a = 1732584193;
        var b = -271733879;
        var c = -1732584194;
        var d = 271733878;
        var e = -1009589776;

        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) 
        {
            var olda = a;
            var oldb = b;
            var oldc = c;
            var oldd = d;
            var olde = e;

            for(var j = 0; j < 80; j++) 
            {
                if(j < 16) 
                    w[j] = x[i + j];
                else 
                    w[j] = rol(w[j-3] ^ w[j-8] ^ w[j-14] ^ w[j-16], 1);
                var t = safe_add(safe_add(rol(a, 5), sha1_ft(j, b, c, d)), safe_add(safe_add(e, w[j]), sha1_kt(j)));
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = rol(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = t;
            }

            a = safe_add(a, olda);
            b = safe_add(b, oldb);
            c = safe_add(c, oldc);
            d = safe_add(d, oldd);
            e = safe_add(e, olde);
        }
        return Array(a, b, c, d, e);
    }

    if (raw == true)
    {
        return str_sha1(str1);
    }
    else
    {
        return hex_sha1(str1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Which part is it that's causing you problems?

Answer (score 3):

The standard library [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) module includes sha1:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> h = hashlib.sha1("lkjlkjlkj")
>>> h.digest()
"N]\x96\xb3:a^6\xa9A}.\x92\xea\xf6\xaa\x19'b{"
>>> h.hexdigest()
'4e5d96b33a615e36a9417d2e92eaf6aa1927627b'
```